# How to keep Fallout: New Vegas from repeatedly crashing

Tags: technical-issues, fallout-new-vegas, windows-10

I had recently purchased Fallout: New Vegas. After a while the game freezes, and a notification comes up to close the program. However, when trying to do so, I cannot see my mouse, and when I try <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, it freezes on New Vegas and Windows, forcing me to restart the computer.
How do I fix this glitch, so the game does not keep crashing?

Note: I am playing the game on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a couple of methods to circumvent the freezing, according to [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fallout/comments/b2fcvr/you_know_when_fallout_new_vegas_freezes_in/) (paraphrasing):

- > Start Task Manager, go to Options, and check "Always on top"!

or

- > Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and if you can’t open Task Manager, choose *Sign In* and hit *Cancel* while it closes what it has open.

([Here](https://help.bethesda.net/#en/answer/35756) is an official Bethesda thread giving a few potential solutions to Fallout: New Vegas crashing on Windows 10 which might prove useful.)

Answer (score 1):

You may need to install +NVSE to help stop the crashing. Also here's an easy fix to close the game without restarting the PC, I just had this problem as well with another game that crashed and I couldn't use Task Manager.

Alt+Tab and open Notepad. Now go to restart and Fallout will close, but the PC won't restart because notepad is open. It'll ask you to close notepad, just click cancel and no restart needed!

Comment: By "+NVSE", do you mean [Unofficial Patch NVSE Plus](https://www.nexusmods.com/newvegas/mods/71239)?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some mods that should help prevent *Fallout: New Vegas* from crashing on Windows 10:

- [OneTweak](https://www.nexusmods.com/newvegas/mods/59266) — allows borderless windowed mode, which helps prevent alt-tab-related crashes
- [FNV 4GB Patcher](https://www.nexusmods.com/newvegas/mods/62552) — make *FNV*  4GB RAM-aware; prevent crashes caused by *FNV*'s 32-bit executable reaching the [2 GB RAM limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2_GB_limit), allowing it to use up to 4 GB RAM on a 64-bit OS.
- [JIP LN](https://www.nexusmods.com/newvegas/mods/58277) — engine bug fixes/tweaks
- [JohnnyGuitar](https://www.nexusmods.com/newvegas/mods/66927) —  engine bug fixes
- [New Vegas Tick Fix - NVTF](https://www.nexusmods.com/newvegas/mods/66537) — performance enhancement and stutter fixing; considered the replacement to the New Vegas Stutter Remover (NVSR), which is no longer maintained.
- [Unofficial Patch NVSE Plus](https://www.nexusmods.com/newvegas/mods/71239) — multiple bug fixes
- [Yukichigai Unofficial Patch - YUP](https://www.nexusmods.com/newvegas/mods/51664) — "A compilation of vital bug fixes for Fallout: New Vegas and its DLC"
- [New Vegas Anti Crash - NVAC](https://www.nexusmods.com/newvegas/mods/53635) — if you still get crashes even with the above mods, then install this mod. It "implements structured exception handling and sanity checking to reduce the frequency of game crashes."

Note that all of the above mods, except YUP, require [xNVSE](https://github.com/xNVSE/NVSE) (updated and maintained version of the New Vegas Script Extender (NVSE)).